# ListView Selected Row Android

Tags: android, listview

I have the following view that is inflated for each row in a listview control:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:background="@drawable/rounded_row"
              android:padding="5dp"
    >
```

For the listview itself, i am setting the list_selecter to this file:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_focused" android:state_focused="true"/>
```

The xml for rounded_row:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#000"/>

    <stroke android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#fff"
        />

    <padding android:left="1dp"
             android:top="1dp"
             android:right="1dp"
             android:bottom="1dp"
        />

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
             android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
             android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
             android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
</shape>
```

and the xml for list_selected_pressed is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#fff"/>

    <stroke android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#ccc"
        />

    <padding android:left="1dp"
             android:top="1dp"
             android:right="1dp"
             android:bottom="1dp"
        />

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
             android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
             android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
             android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
</shape>
```

list_focused

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFEBCD"/>

    <stroke android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#FFFF00"
        />

    <padding android:left="1dp"
             android:top="1dp"
             android:right="1dp"
             android:bottom="1dp"
        />

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
             android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
             android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
             android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
</shape>
```

Purposely, I changed the stroke color. The problem that I was expecting when I press on the list_view_row to see the rounded border color change from white to gray. I am not seeing that at all.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's your `list_selector_focused` ?

Comment: Have you tried applying `list_selecter` to your `list_row` rather than to the `list_view` ?

Comment: I didn't. I believe that is not a valid attribute on a linear layout.

Comment: it looks like it might be working.

Comment: It worked. 

I added android:clickable to the linear layout. Thanks for your tip!!

Comment: I guess I will just add my comment as an answer for other people to see what works for your question.

Comment: I lost my clicks on list view rows not. they don't bubble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please apply your `list_selecter` to your `list_row` rather than to the `list_view`.